# Change the outlook of checkbox as image

Tags: html, css

Hi I have different check boxes and I want to have an image instead of the check boxes so if I click the image the background should change so as to indicate whether it is checked or not.

As I have different checkboxes so I cannot put the background as an image in the CSS. 
Please suggest how should I go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909486/css-replacing-checkbox-image). You can apply this to your code and have the custom background

HTML:

```
<div class="amPmCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[Child][remember_me]" class="checkboxLabel main_street_input" id="am_2" value="1" />
    <label for="am_2">AM</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.amPmCheckbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
.amPmCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]+label {    
    background: url('http://renegadeox.com/img/off.png') no-repeat;
    height:17px;
    padding-left: 18px;
}
.amPmCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background: url('http://renegadeox.com/img/on.png')  no-repeat;
    height:17px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JkDhN/1/

Comment: this is working but if I am adding a div class , its conflicting with my other buttons. they dont work then.

Comment: Post your code. I cannot help you when I do not know what attributes your div class has

Comment: Hi Bijan My image is not displaying full. only the upper half of the image is displayed.

Comment: I dont know how to help short of having the 2 images but I imagine the image size needs to be decreased or checkbox size needs to be increased